# Variable height items in Win32 TreeView using NM_CUSTOMDRAW

Tags: winapi, treeview

Is it possible for items in a WIn32 TreeView control to have variable heights when using NM_CUSTOMDRAW?

Right now, I can successfully select variable sized fonts in the dc in NM_CUSTOMDRAW, but the item texts get clipped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height of each item using the iIntegral member of the TVITEMEX structure that you specify when you insert the item.